# Displaying multiple line graphs on one page

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Im running into some issues displaying multiple graphs on one page.

In my html / php template i have the following

```
<?php
    foreach($charts as $chart) {
        echo '<canvas class="chart" id="'.$chart['id']" width="700" height="200"></canvas>';
    }
?>
```

My Javascript file is as follows:

```
$().ready(function()
{
    $('.chart').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        create_plot($this);
    });
});

function create_plot($this, mode)
{
    if(!$this) return;

    var plot = $this.data('my_plot');
    if(plot) {
        plot.destroy();
        $this.removeData('my_plot');
    }

    var data = {data-in-here};

    var ctx = document.getElementById($this.attr('id'));

    var plot = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
    });

    $this.data('my_plot', plot);
}
```

The problem is that if there are 2 charts in the loop, the same data will display in both charts.

Im very very new to JS, so i prob has this all wrong.

But it seems the plot.destroy is not actually doing anything.

If anyone has any insight, i would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You should view the source of your html, to make sure elements are getting different ID's

Answer (score 0):

The following line is redundant.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById($this.attr('id'));
```

Instead, the `$this` variable is already a pointer to the element.

Meaning - you can do:

```
var plot = new Chart($this, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
});
```

My guess is that php is not creating two different ID's, and javascript is left confused.